# LavaLamp menu is not working on my menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, lavalamp

I have a nav menu for which I want to use a lava lamp jQuery plugin.
In this fiddle example the lava lamp plugin works perfectly: **http://jsfiddle.net/tsLPT/3/** but  on my menu: **http://jsfiddle.net/DMfvx/65/** not working :((  can anyone help me with this because I'm stuck

I want that lava lamp to run only on main UL from my menu and not for children ul.

**Thank You!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error relating to the "currentPageItem" which refers to #selected.

As none of your menu items had an id of "selected", it was failing. By adding an id of "selected" to one of your li's, it now works.

http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/DMfvx/66/

Comment: @ Gavin ah, so simple :) Thank's, one more question , any idea why when I have cursor over child ul lava effect goes to first li from parent ul?

Comment: When you hover over any of the LI's within the drop down menu that appears, it will only change the Left and Width css, not the Top, so it will always go to the first item in the list.